# Error on Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes

Tags: magento-1.7

We try to update some store views with the following command:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array($foundProductID), array('name' => $language['name'], 
              'short_description' => $language['shortDescription'], 
              'description' => $language['desciption'], 
              'meta_description' => $language['metaDescription'], 
              'meta_keyword' => $language['metaKeyword'], 
              'meta_title' => $language['title']), $storeID);
```

Then we get this error message:

```
Fatal error:
Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Event.php on line 167' in app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245 Stack trace:
#0 app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Event.php(167): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/var/www/magent...', 167, Array)
#1 app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Event.php(199): Mage_Index_Model_Event->_mergeNewDataRecursive(false, Array)
#2 app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Event.php(67): Mage_Index_Model_Event->mergePreviousData(Array)
#3 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(423): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Event->_beforeSave(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Event))
#4 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Mode in app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 245
```

We have to update huge amounts of products. That's why we try to use

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes
```

This should be very fast.

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

it may be issue with array();

**first params must be a one dimensional array.**

$foundProductID `is integer value then it is one product id then it is ok` `array($foundProductID)`

or (`$foundProductID itself a array then it not ok`

$foundProductID

```
it may like $foundProductID=array();

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($foundProductID), 

array('name' => $language['name'], 'short_description' => $language['shortDescription'],

'description' => $language['desciption'], 'meta_description' => $language['metaDescription'], 'meta_keyword' => $language['metaKeyword'], 'meta_title' => $language['title']), $storeID);
```

Comment: $foundProductID = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getIdBySku($sku); So it seems to be correct.

Comment: yes..it right... array is right